# Link renders as raw html text

Tags: svn, mod-dav-svn, svn-server

I have a main page like this:

```
== Current Links ==
* [http://173.22.73.107/mediawiki/index.php?title=Tiremwiki:Changelog TIREM Changelog]
* [http://173.22.73.107/bugzilla3/ Bugzilla]
* [http://tempser.alionatigerabear.com/svn/Repository/ SubVersion]
* [http://173.22.73.107/bugzilla3/buglist.cgi?query_format=specific&order=relevance+desc&bug_status=__open__ All open TIREM bugs]
* [http://tempser.alionatigerabear.com/svn/Repository/TIREM-3/trunk/html/index.html TIREM-3 API Documentation]
* [http://tempser.alionatigerabear.com/svn/Repository/TIREM-4/trunk/html/index.html TIREM-4 API Documentation]
```

When I click one of the bottom two links I get raw html source rather than a web page.

What am I doing wrong?

The other links work including the third one to the same server as the last.

Comment: Check the server configuration for tempser.alionatigerabear.com for the "svn/Repository/TIREM-4/trunk/html" directory.  'Betcha it's misconfigured!

Comment: This is not related to mediawiki. It seems your SVN server is configured to output HTML with a text MIME-type.

Comment: It's svn - being annoying and doing what we told it to do. ;-)  svn is just showing source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you have to set `svn:mime-type` property on the files of interest as described in [the book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.advanced.props.html#svn.advanced.props.special.mime-type) and suggested by [svick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41071/svick).

Comment: Thanks for the link and directions.  I'll test it tomorrow.